# Angular Material (v8) module import errors

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm having some annoying issues with the new version of Angular Material. I just upgraded from 7.x.x to 8.1 for Material (and 7.x.x to 8.1 for Angular), but in my `module` imports, I'm getting errors in WebStorm. Not sure if this is related to WebStorm, Angular, or some TS configuration and was wondering if anyone had any ideas.

This is occurring in every module where I import Material modules and for any Material module. It does NOT occur for `component` imports, only the `module` imports.

`ng build --prod`, `ng serve --prod`, and `ng serve` all work fine, but my editor still seems to complain.

Things I've already tried which have not worked:

- Delete `node_modules` and reinstall
- Import from `@angular/material` instead of the specific package (basically revert back to the way it was but keep Material at version 8).

**EDIT**

Per Morphyish's comment, I did a `Code -> Inspect code...` on my entire project.

Almost everywhere I import a module from angular is broken. For example, I'm using the `@angular/flex-layout` so all of my `fxFlex` attributes are giving me "unknown HTML tag" errors. Even the `ReactiveFormsModule` is saying it's an invalid imported symbol. The project `ng serve`s and `ng build`s correctly, so I don't know what's going on.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstorm, and all Intellij IDEs really, can be a bit slow to parse all your files and update the errors and auto-completion. Give it a bit of time and it should be fine again. Sometimes restarting your IDE can help if it's really an issue but it shouldn't affect your project.

If you think you might have an issue with your actual files, you can always try to make sure the folder/file are actually in your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Yeah, I've ran into problems like that before and restarting the IDE did the trick... but not this time :(

Comment: I don't have an angular project I could check right now, but can you access the menu definition from your file ? (ctrl + click on the path or the import). Worst case you can try to force an inspection of the entire project from the `Code` menu, or even rebooting the entire computer to try and clear some application cache.

Comment: Hey, that came up with A LOT more issues... haha. I'll write it above.

Comment: I have a feeling your IDE is drunk and can't compute your node_modules folder properly. The fact that it's still compiling properly point to an IDE issue rather than a framework or bundle issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, sometimes you just need to turn it off then on again. Morphyish was right, my IDE was drunk. I created a new project and copy/pasted all the files from my current project into it and ran `Code -> Inspect Code...` again. None of the errors from the original issue showed up. So I'm accepting Morphyish's answer as correct because he helped a lot, but if at first you don't succeed --- nuke everything.